# Duplicate List Items in Angular: Unable to select first item

Tags: angularjs

I have a list (select) box which is dynamically populated with numbers. Some of these numbers may be duplicates of previous entries. When I attempt to select a duplicate number which has an index lower than the other duplicate value, the list jumps to the higher indexed entry (lower down the list). I have created an example here - http://plnkr.co/edit/D8cVIauJQGOfZx9HdGsD?p=preview . Selecting the first value of 90 will show the above mentioned behavior. Selecting other, non-duplicate, entries works as expected.

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read that ng-repeat doesn't allow duplicate values in an array (I believe it's because it hashes the values into an id to keep track of the entries).

It could be that ng-options also doesn't allow duplicate entries.  I modified your plnkr to use objects in the array with an additional property to disambiguate them.  It now displays the same list and works correctly.

http://plnkr.co/edit/13cG9S6CubdaaZOfk3CR?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. That might work, however, I notice that using this method again puts back the empty option as the first entry.

Comment: An oversite on my part.  The ng-model variable has to be an exact match to the array element for it to be selected.  If it doesn't match anything then it displays a blank entry.  I've updated it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/q11ZfJzVmkxLomz74gDC?p=preview